# This groove encode what? #javascript

Tags: javascript

This groove enc ode what?
and how to decode it ?
I try to decode it with ddecode.com but still can not
and I tried to use closure-compiler.appspot.com/home also can not

please help me

```
    var _0x756b=["\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65","\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x63\x65","\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x23\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x70\x61\x73\x73","\x50\x72\x6F\x67\x72\x65\x73\x73\x3A\x20","\x2F","\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x2E\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x2D\x61\x6D\x6F\x75\x6E\x74","\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72","\x25","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x63\x73\x73","\x2E\x70\x72\x6F\x67\x72\x65\x73\x73\x20\x2E\x62\x61\x72","\x25\x20\x5B","\x5D\x20","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x23\x74\x76\x6D\x69\x74\x5F\x6C\x69\x76\x65\x5F\x63\x6F\x75\x6E\x74","","\x23\x74\x76\x6D\x69\x74\x5F\x64\x69\x65\x5F\x63\x6F\x75\x6E\x74","\x23\x74\x76\x6D\x69\x74\x5F\x77\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x5F\x63\x6F\x75\x6E\x74","\x3c\x69\x6d\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3d\x27\x2f\x61\x73\x73\x65\x74\x73\x2f\x69\x6d\x67\x2f\x63\x6c\x65\x61\x72\x2e\x67\x69\x66\x27\x2f\x3e","\x23\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x53\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73","\x23\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x23\x73\x74\x6F\x70","\x44\x6F\x6E\x65","\x61\x62\x6F\x72\x74","\x0A","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x76\x61\x6C","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x61\x6c\x69\x65\x6e\x30\x37\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x3c\x69\x6d\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3d\x27\x2f\x61\x73\x73\x65\x74\x73\x2f\x69\x6d\x67\x2f\x6c\x6f\x61\x64\x69\x6e\x67\x2e\x67\x69\x66\x27\x2f\x3e","\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x3D\x31\x26\x64\x6F\x3D\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x26\x63\x63\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x3D","\x6D\x73\x67","\x3C\x62\x72\x20\x2F\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64","\x23\x77\x72\x6F\x6E\x67","\x45\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x21\x20\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x63\x74\x20\x41\x64\x6D\x69\x6E\x2E","\x53\x6F\x6D\x65\x74\x68\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x77\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x62\x61\x64\x6C\x79\x20\x77\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x21","\x23\x62\x61\x64\x73\x6F\x63\x6B","\x23\x74\x76\x6D\x69\x74\x5F\x64\x69\x65","\x23\x74\x76\x6D\x69\x74\x5F\x6C\x69\x76\x65","\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72","\x61\x6A\x61\x78","\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x23\x66\x61\x69\x6C","\x74\x72\x69\x6D","No Cards Found!","\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x23\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74","\x23\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x2D\x70\x72\x6F\x67\x72\x65\x73\x73","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79","#socks"];
var ajaxCall;
var docTitle=document[_0x756b[0]];
var a=0;
Array[_0x756b[2]][_0x756b[1]]=function(_0xa295x4){var _0xa295x5=this[_0x756b[3]](_0xa295x4);if(_0xa295x5!=-1){this[_0x756b[4]](_0xa295x5,1);};return this;};function enableTextArea(_0xa295x7){$(_0x756b[7])[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5],_0xa295x7);};function updateProgress(a,_0xa295x9){$(_0x756b[11])[_0x756b[10]](_0x756b[8]+a+_0x756b[9]+_0xa295x9);var _0xa295xa=Math[_0x756b[12]](a/_0xa295x9*100);$(_0x756b[16])[_0x756b[15]](_0x756b[14],_0xa295xa+_0x756b[13])[_0x756b[10]](_0xa295xa+_0x756b[13]);document[_0x756b[0]]=_0xa295xa+_0x756b[17]+a+_0x756b[9]+_0xa295x9+_0x756b[18]+docTitle;};function tvmit_liveUp(){var _0xa295xc=parseInt($(_0x756b[20])[_0x756b[19]]());_0xa295xc++;$(_0x756b[20])[_0x756b[19]](_0xa295xc+_0x756b[21]);};function tvmit_dieUp(){var _0xa295xc=parseInt($(_0x756b[22])[_0x756b[19]]());_0xa295xc++;$(_0x756b[22])[_0x756b[19]](_0xa295xc+_0x756b[21]);};function tvmit_wrongUp(){var _0xa295xc=parseInt($(_0x756b[23])[_0x756b[19]]());_0xa295xc++;$(_0x756b[23])[_0x756b[19]](_0xa295xc+_0x756b[21]);};function stopLoading(_0xa295x7){$(_0x756b[25])[_0x756b[19]](_0x756b[24]);enableTextArea(false);$(_0x756b[26])[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5],false);$(_0x756b[27])[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5],true);if(_0xa295x7){alert(_0x756b[28]);}else{ajaxCall[_0x756b[29]]();};};function updateTextBox(_0xa295x11){var _0xa295x12=$(_0x756b[7])[_0x756b[32]]()[_0x756b[31]](_0x756b[30]);_0xa295x12[_0x756b[1]](_0xa295x11);$(_0x756b[7])[_0x756b[32]](_0xa295x12[_0x756b[33]](_0x756b[30]));};function OKTY(_0xa295x14,_0xa295x15,_0xa295x16,_0xa295x17){if(_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]]<1||_0xa295x15>=_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]]){stopLoading(true);return false;};
 if (_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]] > 100) {
        alert('UPS!! ONLY 100CC/CHECK!!!');
        stopLoading(true);
        return false;
    };
    if(_0xa295x17>=_0xa295x16){OKTY(_0xa295x14,_0xa295x15,_0xa295x16,0);return false;};updateTextBox(_0xa295x14[_0xa295x15]);ajaxCall=$[_0x756b[50]]({url:_0x756b[35],dataType:_0x756b[36],cache:false,type:_0x756b[37],beforeSend:function(_0xa295x18){$(_0x756b[25])[_0x756b[19]](_0x756b[38]);},data:_0x756b[39]+encodeURIComponent(_0xa295x14[_0xa295x15]),success:function(_0xa295x19){switch(_0xa295x19[_0x756b[49]]){case-1:_0xa295x15++;$(_0x756b[43])[_0x756b[42]](_0xa295x19[_0x756b[40]]+_0x756b[41]);updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]]);tvmit_wrongUp();break;;case 1:;case 12:alert(_0x756b[44]);throw new Error(_0x756b[45]);break;;case 3:$(_0x756b[46])[_0x756b[42]](_0xa295x19[_0x756b[40]]);updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]]);break;;case 2:_0xa295x15++;$(_0x756b[47])[_0x756b[42]](_0xa295x19[_0x756b[40]]+_0x756b[41]);_0xa295x17++;updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]]);tvmit_dieUp();break;;case 0:_0xa295x15++;$(_0x756b[48])[_0x756b[42]](_0xa295x19[_0x756b[40]]+_0x756b[41]);tvmit_liveUp();updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14[_0x756b[34]]);break;;};OKTY(_0xa295x14,_0xa295x15,_0xa295x16,_0xa295x17);}});return true;};function filterMP(a){var _0xa295x1b=a[_0x756b[31]](_0x756b[30]);var _0xa295x1c=new Array();var _0xa295x14=new Array();for(var _0xa295x18=0;_0xa295x18<_0xa295x1b[_0x756b[34]];_0xa295x18++){if(_0xa295x1b[_0xa295x18][_0x756b[34]]>0){var _0xa295x1d=/(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})/g;var _0xa295x1e=_0xa295x1b[_0xa295x18][_0x756b[51]](_0xa295x1d);if(null==_0xa295x1e||!LuhnCheck(_0xa295x1e[0])){continue;};if(_0xa295x1c[_0x756b[3]](_0xa295x1e[0])==-1){_0xa295x1c[_0x756b[52]](_0xa295x1e[0]);_0xa295x14[_0x756b[52]](_0xa295x1b[_0xa295x18]);};};};return _0xa295x14;};var LuhnCheck=function(){var a=[0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9];return function(_0xa295x9){var _0xa295xa=0;var _0xa295x20;var _0xa295x18=false;var _0xa295x1d=String(_0xa295x9)[_0x756b[53]](/[^\d]/g,_0x756b[21]);if(0==_0xa295x1d[_0x756b[34]]){return false;};for(var _0xa295x1e=_0xa295x1d[_0x756b[34]]-1;_0xa295x1e>=0;--_0xa295x1e){_0xa295x20=parseInt(_0xa295x1d[_0x756b[54]](_0xa295x1e),10);_0xa295xa+=(_0xa295x18=!_0xa295x18)?_0xa295x20:a[_0xa295x20];};return _0xa295xa%10==0;};}();
    $(document)[_0x756b[62]](function() {
    $(_0x756b[27])[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5], true)[_0x756b[55]](function() {
        stopLoading(false);
    });
    $(_0x756b[26])[_0x756b[55]](function() {
        var _0xa295x12 = filterMP($(_0x756b[7])[_0x756b[32]]());
        var _0xa295x16 = parseInt($(_0x756b[56])[_0x756b[32]]());
        var _0xa295x17 = 0;
        if ($(_0x756b[7])[_0x756b[32]]()[_0x756b[57]]() == _0x756b[21]) {
            alert(_0x756b[58]);
            return false;
        };

        $(_0x756b[7])[_0x756b[32]](_0xa295x12[_0x756b[33]](_0x756b[30]))[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5], true);
        $(_0x756b[60])[_0x756b[59]]();
        $(_0x756b[61])[_0x756b[59]]();
        $(_0x756b[26])[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5], true);
        $(_0x756b[27])[_0x756b[6]](_0x756b[5], false);
        updateProgress(0, _0xa295x12[_0x756b[34]]);
        OKTY(_0xa295x12, 0, _0xa295x16, 0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `_0x756b` declared at the top is an array of strings, used to reference various properties throughout the rest of the code. Try pasting the array into your console, and you'll see all the strings:

```
["title", "remove", "prototype", "indexOf", "splice", "disabled", "attr", "#mailpass",
 "Progress: ", "/", "text", ".check-amount", "floor", "%", "width", "css",
 ".progress .bar", "% [", "] ", "html", "#tvmit_live_count", "", "#tvmit_die_count",
 "#tvmit_wrong_count", "<img src='/assets/img/clear.gif'/>", "#checkStatus", "#submit",
 "#stop", "Done", "abort", "\n", "split", "val", "join", "length", "alien07.php", "json",
 "POST", "<img src='/assets/img/loading.gif'/>", "ajax=1&do=check&cclist=", "msg",
 "<br />", "append", "#wrong", "Error! Contact Admin.", "Something went badly wrong!",
 "#badsock", "#tvmit_die", "#tvmit_live", "error", "ajax", "match", "push", "replace",
 "charAt", "click", "#fail", "trim", "No Cards Found!", "show", "#result",
 "#check-progress", "ready", "#socks"]
```

Replacing all of the `_0x756b[##]` with their respective strings, you get:

```
var ajaxCall;
var docTitle=document["title"];
var a=0;
Array["prototype"]["remove"]=function(_0xa295x4){var _0xa295x5=this["indexOf"](_0xa295x4);if(_0xa295x5!=-1){this["splice"](_0xa295x5,1);};return this;};function enableTextArea(_0xa295x7){$("#mailpass")["attr"]("disabled",_0xa295x7);};function updateProgress(a,_0xa295x9){$(".check-amount")["text"]("Progress: "+a+"/"+_0xa295x9);var _0xa295xa=Math["floor"](a/_0xa295x9*100);$(".progress .bar")["css"]("width",_0xa295xa+"%")["text"](_0xa295xa+"%");document["title"]=_0xa295xa+"% ["+a+"/"+_0xa295x9+"] "+docTitle;};function tvmit_liveUp(){var _0xa295xc=parseInt($("#tvmit_live_count")["html"]());_0xa295xc++;$("#tvmit_live_count")["html"](_0xa295xc+"");};function tvmit_dieUp(){var _0xa295xc=parseInt($("#tvmit_die_count")["html"]());_0xa295xc++;$("#tvmit_die_count")["html"](_0xa295xc+"");};function tvmit_wrongUp(){var _0xa295xc=parseInt($("#tvmit_wrong_count")["html"]());_0xa295xc++;$("#tvmit_wrong_count")["html"](_0xa295xc+"");};function stopLoading(_0xa295x7){$("#checkStatus")["html"]("<img src='/assets/img/clear.gif'/>");enableTextArea(false);$("#submit")["attr"]("disabled",false);$("#stop")["attr"]("disabled",true);if(_0xa295x7){alert("Done");}else{ajaxCall["abort"]();};};function updateTextBox(_0xa295x11){var _0xa295x12=$("#mailpass")["val"]()["split"]("
");_0xa295x12["remove"](_0xa295x11);$("#mailpass")["val"](_0xa295x12["join"]("
"));};function OKTY(_0xa295x14,_0xa295x15,_0xa295x16,_0xa295x17){if(_0xa295x14["length"]<1||_0xa295x15>=_0xa295x14["length"]){stopLoading(true);return false;};
 if (_0xa295x14["length"] > 100) {
        alert('UPS!! ONLY 100CC/CHECK!!!');
        stopLoading(true);
        return false;
    };
    if(_0xa295x17>=_0xa295x16){OKTY(_0xa295x14,_0xa295x15,_0xa295x16,0);return false;};updateTextBox(_0xa295x14[_0xa295x15]);ajaxCall=$["ajax"]({url:"alien07.php",dataType:"json",cache:false,type:"POST",beforeSend:function(_0xa295x18){$("#checkStatus")["html"]("<img src='/assets/img/loading.gif'/>");},data:"ajax=1&do=check&cclist="+encodeURIComponent(_0xa295x14[_0xa295x15]),success:functio…teProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14["length"]);tvmit_wrongUp();break;;case 1:;case 12:alert("Error! Contact Admin.");throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");break;;case 3:$("#badsock")["append"](_0xa295x19["msg"]);updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14["length"]);break;;case 2:_0xa295x15++;$("#tvmit_die")["append"](_0xa295x19["msg"]+"<br />");_0xa295x17++;updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14["length"]);tvmit_dieUp();break;;case 0:_0xa295x15++;$("#tvmit_live")["append"](_0xa295x19["msg"]+"<br />");tvmit_liveUp();updateProgress(_0xa295x15,_0xa295x14["length"]);break;;};OKTY(_0xa295x14,_0xa295x15,_0xa295x16,_0xa295x17);}});return true;};function filterMP(a){var _0xa295x1b=a["split"]("
");var _0xa295x1c=new Array();var _0xa295x14=new Array();for(var _0xa295x18=0;_0xa295x18<_0xa295x1b["length"];_0xa295x18++){if(_0xa295x1b[_0xa295x18]["length"]>0){var _0xa295x1d=/(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})/g;var _0xa295x1e=_0xa295x1b[_0xa295x18]["match"](_0xa295x1d);if(null==_0xa295x1e||!LuhnCheck(_0xa295x1e[0])){continue;};if(_0xa295x1c["indexOf"](_0xa295x1e[0])==-1){_0xa295x1c["push"](_0xa295x1e[0]);_0xa295x14["push"](_0xa295x1b[_0xa295x18]);};};};return _0xa295x14;};var LuhnCheck=function(){var a=[0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9];return function(_0xa295x9){var _0xa295xa=0;var _0xa295x20;var _0xa295x18=false;var _0xa295x1d=String(_0xa295x9)["replace"](/[^\d]/g,"");if(0==_0xa295x1d["length"]){return false;};for(var _0xa295x1e=_0xa295x1d["length"]-1;_0xa295x1e>=0;--_0xa295x1e){_0xa295x20=parseInt(_0xa295x1d["charAt"](_0xa295x1e),10);_0xa295xa+=(_0xa295x18=!_0xa295x18)?_0xa295x20:a[_0xa295x20];};return _0xa295xa%10==0;};}();
    $(document)["ready"](function() {
    $("#stop")["attr"]("disabled", true)["click"](function() {
        stopLoading(false);
    });
    $("#submit")["click"](function() {
        var _0xa295x12 = filterMP($("#mailpass")["val"]());
        var _0xa295x16 = parseInt($("#fail")["val"]());
        var _0xa295x17 = 0;
        if ($("#mailpass")["val"]()["trim"]() == "") {
            alert("No Cards Found!");
            return false;
        };

        $("#mailpass")["val"](_0xa295x12["join"]("
"))["attr"]("disabled", true);
        $("#result")["show"]();
        $("#check-progress")["show"]();
        $("#submit")["attr"]("disabled", true);
        $("#stop")["attr"]("disabled", false);
        updateProgress(0, _0xa295x12["length"]);
        OKTY(_0xa295x12, 0, _0xa295x16, 0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I'll leave the rest up to you.

Comment: when it appears this output what else?
Failed to load resource: the http://test.visualbasic87.ml/test/alien07.php server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I don't know the context; you'll have to play around and figure it out yourself. Try renaming the variables to make it more understandable.

Answer (score -1):

Hi the first line is hex `"\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65"` you can find easy a hex decode on google